# Is there a way for to store bookmarks and favorites so that I can access from more than a single computer?

Tags: links, bookmarks

I have a large number of bookmarked sites and links that I want to be able to access on other computers that I use. Is there a way for me to share or access these without having to sync them by hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in Firefox and several other browsers using a plugin called Xmarks, in Safari using MobileMe, or in Chrome with Google's built-in Chrome Sync (in the Preferences menu).

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it in IE, as well, but I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Xmarks actually works with IE, FF, Chrome and Safari so you can keep the same bookmarks across all browsers on multiple machines. (I use FF at home and Chrome at work and it syncs both)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Google Chrome you can synchronise bookmarks to use across multiple computers.

Select **(Spanner) > Options > Personal Stuff**

Then the top option **Sync**

You need a Google account to be able to do this.

You can select whether you sync any or all of Bookmarks, Preferences and Themes.

Comment: What's weird is if you then go to your Google Docs account, you will see your bookmarks stored there as well. I don't think you can edit them though.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try [Delicious](http://delicious.com/). They do have a firefox plugin that allows you to sync automatically between the website and your browser if you wish. And you can save your bookmarks in delicious rather than the browser bookmarks if you prefer. They have tools for importing/exporting bookmarks from your browser when you first set up. Plus you have the added advantage of being able to access your bookmarks even if you are not on your personal machine(s). Delicious does allow you to keep your bookmarks private if you wish.

The only downside is that you will be organizing bookmarks by Tag rather than directory as you would normally, but personally I found I got used to that pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a Firefox user, you can use [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/), it will automatically keep all of your bookmarks in sync between any of your Firefox browsers, even the newest Firefox mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

> `ReadItLater`

a plug-in for all browsers and can also be accessed online ...Even on Iphone